# Visual Studio 2015 C# method overloading intellisense not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015. 
In the past when I type a method that has multiple overloads it would show me those overload options in a tooltip after typing in the opening "(" e.g.

```
return RedirectToAction(
```

also when I type in a "," between parameters. 
However it is not working anymore. Can't remember when.

I thought it is something in my project but the same thing happens in a new console application.

If I go to

- Tools -> Options
- Environment -> Keyboard
- and type in Edit.ParameterInfo

I see the following

[image: keyboard]

for the text editor.

I tried the above text editor by typing in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> it doesn't do anything. I also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> but it also doesn't work

My normal intellisense works when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> so it it just the method overloading intellisense that isn't working

My questions:

1. How do I get it top show the various methods like it use to when I enter "(" after the method name?
2. Why isn't they keyboard shortcut working to show method overloading intellisense?

Comment: I think I have [a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33282357/1016343) for you ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - have you tried the tips mentioned here?

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/48807/how-to-resolve-intellisense-issue-in-visual-studio.aspx

For me the following worked (mentioned in the blog above as solution 1+2):

1. Go to **Tools** => **Options** => **Text Editor** => **All Languages** => **General**
2. Enable **"Auto List Members"** and **"Parameter Information"**
3. Now **restart Visual Studio** and try again.

**N.B.** After the restart of VS it worked for me (Steps 1+2 without restart were **not** suffient).

But you may go through all the **9 steps mentioned** in the blog if required.